# Multiple Persistence Units Ignored by OpenJPA ant task while Build TIme Enhancement

Tags: java, ejb, openjpa

I have an EJB Project, which has persistence.xml, which inturn has 2 persistence units. I'm doing build time enhancement using OpenJPA ant task. The problem is, it enhances only the classes mentioned in first persistence unit. The classes in the other persistence units are ignored.

Persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

```
<persistence-unit name="ora_agen_test"
    transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/ora_agen</jta-data-source>
    <jar-file>some.jar</jar-file>
    <class>company.some.entity.account3</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="openjpa.ConnectionURL"
            value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//dbsrvoractc32:1521/oractc32" />
        <property name="openjpa.ConnectionUserName" value="agenproc" />
        <property name="openjpa.ConnectionPassword" value="yUqM2~GK" />
        <property name="openjpa.ConnectionDriverName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
        <property name="openjpa.jdbc.Schema" value="agen" />
        <property name="openjpa.Log" value="log4j" />
        <property name="openjpa.ConnectionFactoryProperties"
            value="PrettyPrint=true, PrettyPrintLineLength=72, PrintParameters=true" />
        <property name="openjpa.RuntimeUnenhancedClasses" value="unsupported" />
        <property name="openjpa.ConnectionRetainMode" value="transaction" />
        <property name="openjpa.jdbc.DBDictionary" value="JoinSyntax=sql92" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>

<persistence-unit name="ora_acnt_test"
    transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/ora_acnt</jta-data-source>
    <jar-file>some.jar</jar-file>
    <class>company.some.entity.Account1</class>
    <class>company.some.entity.Account2</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="openjpa.ConnectionURL"
            value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//dbsrvoractc32:1521/oractc32" />
        <property name="openjpa.ConnectionUserName" value="acntproc" />
        <property name="openjpa.ConnectionPassword" value=":kU|31iE" />
        <property name="openjpa.ConnectionDriverName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
        <property name="openjpa.jdbc.Schema" value="acnt" />
        <property name="openjpa.Log" value="log4j" />
        <property name="openjpa.ConnectionFactoryProperties"
            value="PrettyPrint=true, PrettyPrintLineLength=72, PrintParameters=true" />
        <property name="openjpa.RuntimeUnenhancedClasses" value="unsupported" />
        <property name="openjpa.ConnectionRetainMode" value="transaction" />
        <property name="openjpa.jdbc.DBDictionary" value="JoinSyntax=sql92" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Ant Script ( target ):

`<target name="enhance" depends="jarchive_nomanifest,jarchive_manifest"
        description="Write out enhance data used during the build">
        <startBuildActivity repositoryAddress="${repositoryAddress}"
            userId="${userId}" passwordFile="${passwordFile}" parentActivityID="${parentActivityId}"
            activityIdProperty="activityId" label="Enhance Information of ${name}"
            autoComplete="false" verbose="true" buildResultUUID="${buildInfo.buildResultUUID}" />
        <openjpac>
            <config propertiesFile="${dir.src}/META-INF/persistence.xml" />
        <!--    <fileset dir="${dir.build}/bin">
                <include name="**/*" />
            </fileset> -->
            <classpath refid="application.classpath" />
        </openjpac>
        <completeBuildActivity repositoryAddress="${repositoryAddress}"
            userId="${userId}" passwordFile="${passwordFile}" activityId="${activityId}"
            verbose="true" buildResultUUID="${buildInfo.buildResultUUID}" />
    </target>`
        
        
            
        
                
            </fileset> -->